# How can I define an object to have different fields using typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function:

```
function getAdminParams(entity) {
   params = {};
   params = {
                pk: "0006000",
                param: "?pk=0006000",
                table: "Content",
                success: true
            };
  return params;
}
```

In another file I use this function like this:

```
params = getAdminParams(entity);
    if (params.success) {
```

Is there a way that I could use intellisense so that the params object
shows as having a "success" parameter? I saw that Typescript has classes and interfaces but I am not sure how or if I can use these as a return type.

Comment: I'm not sure about typescript, but note that from a JavaScript point of view the first line of the function `params = {}` is not needed. It creates an empty object that will be thrown away when you assign `params` equal to a different object on the next line. Also, not declaring `params` with `var` inside that function means you're updating a global `params`. You don't really need the `params` variable at all within the function for a simple case like that: you can just return an object literal directly with `return { ... }` (make sure you put the starting `{` on the same line as `return`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define params as an interface, then you can use a colon after the function parentheses to declare it as the return type of `getAdminParams()`. Like this:

```
interface IParams {
    success: bool;
    pk: string;
    // etc...
}

function getAdminParams(entity): IParams {
    params = {
                pk: "0006000",
                success: true
                // etc...
            };
    return params; // If the properties assigned do not fulfill the IParams interface, this will be marked as an error.
}

params = getAdminParams(entity);
if (params. // Intellisense should offer success and pk and any other properties of IParams).
```

Within `getAdminParams` you could explicitly declare `params` as a new `IParams`, but type inference will set up the intellisense for you even if you don't, as long as the properties you assign to the `params` object fulfill the contract specified in the `IParams` interface.

Of course your return type could be a class, or a string, or any other type, and you would declare that using the `function f(): returnType` syntax in just the same way.

The [language specification](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267238) covers all of this in great detail, or there is a shorter introduction here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/469280/An-introduction-to-Type-Script or a similar SO question here: [How to declare Return Types for Functions in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736269/how-to-declare-return-types-for-functions-in-typescript?rq=1)