# How to change number or boolean type to just number type for returned value?

Tags: typescript

I created this simple function that returns 2 values - `isNumber` and `convertedValue`. I expect `isNumber` to be boolean type and `convertedValue` to be number type, but when I extract those values, I get `number | boolean` type for both values. How can I make changes so when I extract them that I get boolean type for `isNumber` and number type for `convertedValue` ?

```
    const numberValidator = (val: string, fn: (str: string) => number) => {
      const convertedValue = fn(val);
      const isNumber =
        typeof convertedValue === 'number' && isFinite(convertedValue);
      return [isNumber, convertedValue];
    };
```

```
        const [isNumber, convertedValue] = numberValidator(
          val,
          Number
        ); // now type for both values are "number | boolean"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare Return Types for Functions in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736269/how-to-declare-return-types-for-functions-in-typescript). In your case, the return type would be `[boolean, number]`, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the correct return type, you can use [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) behind the tuple.

```
const numberValidator = (val: string, fn: (str: string) => number) => {
  const convertedValue = fn(val);
  const isNumber =
    typeof convertedValue === "number" && isFinite(convertedValue);
  return [isNumber, convertedValue] as const;
};

const [isNumber, convertedValue] = numberValidator("abc", Number);

isNumber
// ^? const isNumber: boolean

convertedValue
// ^? const convertedValue: number
```

Otherwise, TypeScript will widen it to an array type `(number | boolean)[]`. But you want the tuple type `[boolean, number]`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCuBbARgUwE4DUCGAbAlgCbZQjowC8MAFAG54BcM06+YA5gDQwBmYT1FkxZt2ASkoA+OEjToJFaQG8AUDBihIsTbQxRUhHLnipKvMHTxiA3Go3hoMfBABysjJTvqoATwAOqCA89mC66PqGeCaUFFQARAgoGHEwAGSpThAAYmz4+tQ6egZGJjZ26KhQ8OhgMADazm5J6NyF4cVRqAC6MNgQIdC2AL62KpqODa7uLSFhESXdZolyRkQkZNRx2MjAcdxNcmUqjdMqAPRnMAB6APwDsCfNTMggILio2GAqY+BzHcaoc6XW73WZFSIApjLDAqIA)

Comment: I notice using object `{isNumber, convertedValue}` works too as per "KALrious" answer. Would you know why {} does not return `number | boolean` type?

Comment: @JudoboyAlex Do you understand what `{x}` is in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do as follow:

```js
const numberValidator = (val: string, fn: (str: string) => number) => {
  const convertedValue = fn(val);
  const isNumber =
    typeof convertedValue === "number" && isFinite(convertedValue);
  return {isNumber, convertedValue};
};

const {isNumber, convertedValue} = numberValidator("1", Number);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. Can you please explain why { } and [ ] returns different type?

Comment: There are few differences between the code in this answer and the code in the question. Some explanation of the changes you made, and how they solve the problem are likely warranted. Also, snippets only handle JavaScript, not TypeScript.

Comment: the thing is with your version of numberValidator you are returning an Array of two possible value, the first one is a bool and the second one is a number.
That's why in TS you got an `Array<bool | number>`.
But in my version you are returning a object which type is define like this:
`type ReturnObject = {
 isNumber: boolean,
 convertedValued: number
}`
hope it help